# Find files with their own name in the content

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I would like to know how, using Bash, I can display the names of all the files in a folder that have their name in the text?

e.g. file.txt has name "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **file** consectetur adipiscing elit." in its content and file file2.txt:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

there is no word "file2", so it will be skipped

I know I should use "grep", but I'm not sure exactly how to use it in this case

Comment: Did you try something? If you have a filename in a parameter `f`, you could check if it contains its own name with `grep -q -e "$f" "$f"`, and once you have that, you need a loop over all the files you're interested in.

Comment: `for f in *; do grep -F "${f%%.*}" "$f"; done`

Answer (score 0):

You have **not** indicated whether you care that the match on filename is where it is a **substring of a different filename**.

Assuming you don't care about that, the solution is simplified by using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), and might look like this (*as you can see, I built test data in the script*):

```
#!/bin/sh

Fname="junk_38.input"

cat >"${Fname}" <<-!EnDoFfIlE
make my day!
123
how are you?
${Fname}
yabadabadoo!
abc
let the force be with you!
!EnDoFfIlE

ls -l "${Fname}"

awk -v fName="${Fname}" 'BEGIN{
    hit=0 ;
}{
    if( index( $0, fName ) > 0 ){
        hit=1 ;
        exit ;
    } ;
}END{
    if( hit == 1 ){
        printf("MATCH: %s [%s]\n", fName,NR ) ;
    }else{
        printf("NO_MATCH: %s [%s]\n", fName, NR ) ;
    } ;
}' <"${Fname}"
```

This solution gives you the line number where the match was found, and exits at the first instance encountered.  It also reports the number of lines examined (equivalent to wc -l) for files where no match was found.